# Get Current date & time with [NSDate date]

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate

My system's  date time is 26 May 22:55 but when i get date with `[NSDate date]` date time is 27 May 02:35

is it  because of time zone ?

if yes how to solve this problem, that when i get date time, give me the date of my system and doesn't check time zone

Comment: How are you determining what the date object is? Are you just logging it? If so, it will likely print its time as UTC. So, yes, it's the time zone. The object has the correct date and time, it's just formatting it for display in Coordinated Universal Time.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

```
NSLocale* currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
[[NSDate date] descriptionWithLocale:currentLocale];
```

or use

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
// or @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a" if you prefer the time with AM/PM 
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Comment: for the newbies (and to state the obvious)... it's NSLog, not NSlog in the last line... just a typo.

Comment: Another little glitch. `@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"` is not a nice date format, as it will give 0-12 time with no AM/PM suffix.  A better one is `@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"` or `@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` (for 0-24 time format).